# Accessibility Services missing

Tags: settings, accessibility

I am using a Huawei tablet with Android 4.3 jellybean OS (EMUI), and for some reason I do not see any accessibility **SERVICES** (only **SYSTEM** is there) *see below:*

[image: Missing accessibility services]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

> Typically under Settings → Accessibility there is SERVICES such as
>   Talkback, or other applications with accessibility SERVICES etc).

Currently I utilise a workaround which uses Secure settings plugin together with Tasker to  switch accessibility SERVICES, but still the accessibility SERVICES won't appear under Accessibility in Settings, making it difficult for me to know whether the accessibility service for a certain app will be functional at a given time.

This short term fix works **but** is not very effective since I won't be sure if the required accessibility SERVICE will be turned on/off at the required moment or not.

Is there a way to make **Accessibility SERVICES** appear in **Settings**? I am comfortable any kind of system files modifications as long as it fixes the issue.

(Additional info: I have tried flashing different stock ROMs provided at manufacturer's website but it seems they all have the same problem)

I can't seem to find compatible custom ROMs that are free from this "bug" also the latest android version on the tablet is 4.3, **nothing newer than this**.

Comment: This is the question that initially brought me to Stack Exchange :)

Comment: Google for *hidden settings* on Play Store. One of them may work for you :)

Comment: I think it was this app I used (not sure) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher

Comment: @beeshyams I tried the app you mentioned (and other related ones more than 5 different apps) but they don't seem to solve  the issue. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Fine. let the suggestions be retained, so that someone else may not suggest the same. Once you are done, please flag them for deletion

Comment: In case you don't get what you are hoping for, you can try this workaround. The table secure in *Settings storage* database contains the key `enabled_accessibility_services`. Its value shows the apps (components) which have the accessibility service enabled. You can parse that key in Tasker and have a Scene (Tasker) let you see them formatted.

Comment: @beeshyams Since the question hasn't received an answer yet I decided to post the workaround I have been using, in case it helps other users. But I am still open to any suggestions.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks, currently I had been using secure settings as  a workaround, and if you can add to or improve it feel free to write separate answer which I will happily award the bounty –

Comment: @Firelord how do I create a scene to show these enabled accessibility with Tasker? I haven't played a bit with scenes, a little help will be appreciated.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I'm currently short on time, else, I would have posted a working and detailed answer. May I suggest you try the sub-reddit of Tasker. The community there would definitely provide pointers.

Comment: Not sure about Android 4.3 but in certain devices such as Huawei, accessibility options might be under 'advanced' or 'more' as a submenu. Are you sure that accessibility doesn't exist as a submenu in another area?

Comment: @papakias No I checked everywhere and I couldn't find it

Answer (score 3):

Since the bounty expired (went unawarded) and this question hasn't received an answer yet, I just decided to explain the **short term workaround** as it may help users facing a similar problem.

---

**Why I needed this feature**:

- In order to use my productivity apps such as AutoInput, Greenify etc
- To be able to monitor which applications whose accessibility settings are enabled at a given moment.
- To be able to switch on or off from native interface with ease.

[image]

---

The pre requisites for this workaround include:

- [Secure settings plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&hl=en) (in app add-ons)
- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) ( 7 day free trial with option to purchase)
- [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) see [Minimal ADB setup](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979)  and [instructions](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)

**Workthrough;**

- First we need to grant Secure settings  these permissions:

```
    adb shell pm grant com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

`adb shell pm grant com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`

- Now we need to open Tasker to create a task for toggling the accessibility service of a certain application.
- Go to Task tab and select "New Task + "
  You can name this Task anything (e.g *Enable AccServ*).
- Click "+" to add new Action
  Code → Plugin → Secure Settings ,
  [**Configuration**: {*System+ Actions* → (select target App to enable(or disable) accessibility service e.g `Autoinput:service.ServiceAccesibility`}]
   Tap on "Save"
- Tap back to exit from this task
- Repeat the proceedure to disable (or enable) accessibility service of the target app (or create a new one).
- Exit all the way back to home screen, and long press home screen to activate widgets, swipe and create a shortcut widget which activates (or deactivate the accessibility service of target app).
- You should be good to go.

---

**Cons**

- The major back backdraw is that you are not able to monitor (in real time) the state of the accessibility service of a certain application, you have to rely on switch the toggles back and forth).
- It is also generally difficult to control
- While this a better workaround than nothing, it is usually time consuming to set up the tasker profiles to handle this.
- It clutters the home screen with too many widgets
- Relatively battery consuming than using built-in feature in UI.
- It requires some paid apps mentioned above

---

Nevertheless this is a fully functional workaround, which I hope can help users with similar problem